# Prove that length of three bisectors determine triangle.

Tags: proof-verification, triangles

All of us know that length of 3 bisectors determine triangle. But actually all proofs that I heard are sufficient large. So I'm interested in short and smart proof.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus no

Comment: This could be difficult to prove since it's _not_ true for equilateral triangles (indeed there are an infinite number of equilateral triangles that all have the same bisectors).  This is what makes this proof difficult (and not "easy") because you should end up proving that it's true for all triangles _except_ equilateral ones.

Comment: @Jared but why? If triangle is equilateral then all bisectors are equal , also: suppose that two different equilateral triangles has the equal bisectors , then they have equal sides, then they equal

Comment: If you're talking about line segments then yes--I assumed you were talking about lines.

Comment: @Jared about line segments, yes

Comment: Wait, are talking about perpendicular bisectors (of each segment) or angle bisectors?

Comment: @Jared angle bisectors

Comment: Because the perpendicular bisectors intersect to form the circumcenter and the angle bisectors intersect to form the incenter.   These can be useful in your proof (the "easy" proof as you want is a geometric one).

Comment: The problem with proving such a case is that it's not like you can just take any three line segments and say they are bisectors.  One, they have to _all three_ intersect (to be bisectors of a triangle).  Further they have to form an incenter, you cannot take any three arbitrary, intersecting, line segments and say they form bisectors of some triangle.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you're talking about angle bisectors then you _are not_ talking about line segments.  Where do you assume the "line segment", i.e. the angle bisector ends?

Comment: @openspace You are interested in short elegant proofs that the lengths of the three angle bisectors determine the lengths of the three sides. Is that correct?

Comment: @almagest yes, then if it's true we could say that length of three bisectors determine the triangle

Comment: @openspace Then to avoid all the confusion with Jared please amend the question to "All of us know that the lengths of the three angle bisectors determine the triangle ... "

Comment: @openspace The problem is that what assumptions have to be made, given the three bisectors, such that a triangle can actually be formed!  You have to assume this before proceeding which requires (in the proof) that you show when it cannot happen.  This is what makes this proof very difficult.  Think about it: what can you assume if you _assume_ these are indeed angle bisectors of some triangle and what _cannot_ be assumed otherwise.

Comment: @almagest I don't think that addresses my concern at all.  If you show three line segments that all intersect it's not always possible that they form bisecting angles of a triangle--in fact this is almost trivial to show with any random diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can always look for a smarter proof, but unfortunately a *geometric* proof is unlikely to be available because with the help of more Galois theory than I want to go into one can show that no geometric construction (with ruler and compasses) will allow you to construct the triangle given only the lengths of the angle bisectors. That strongly suggests that any proof will necessarily use algebra/analysis rather than geometry.

Let the sides of the triangle be $a,b,c$ and let the lengths of the three angle bisectors be $l,m,n$. We show first that $$l=\frac{2}{b+c}\sqrt{bcs(s-a)}\ \ (*)$$ where $2s=a+b+c$.

Let the bisector $AD$ have length $l$ (and sides $BC,CA,AB$ have lengths $a,b,c$ respectively). Then area $ABD+\text{area}\ ADC=\text{area}\ ABC$. So we have $bc\sin A=bl\sin\frac{A}{2}+cl\sin\frac{A}{2}$ and hence $l=\frac{2bc}{b+c}\cos\frac{A}{2}$. The cosine formula gives $\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$, so $2\cos^2\frac{A}{2}=1+\cos A=\frac{(b+c)^2-a^2}{2bc}$ and hence $\cos\frac{A}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)}}{bc}$ which gives $(*)$.

Taking $4(*)^2$ we have $4l^2=\frac{4}{(b+c)^2}bc(b+c+a)(b+c-a)=4bc-\frac{4a^2bc}{(b+c)^2}$. Adding $a^2+(b-c)^2$ to both sides we get $4l^2+a^2+(b-c)^2=a^2+(b+c)^2-\frac{4a^2bc}{(b+c)^2}=(b+c)^2+\frac{a^2(b-c)^2}{(b+c)^2}$. We now add $\pm2a(b-c)$ to both sides to get $$4l^2+\left(a\pm(b-c)\right)^2=\left(b+c\pm\frac{a(b-c)}{b+c}\right)^2$$ Taking the square root for each choice of sign and adding we get $$b+c=\sqrt{l^2+(s-b)^2}+\sqrt{l^2+(s-c)^2}$$ [note that $\frac{1}{2}(a+(b-c))=s-c$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a-(b-c))=s-b$]. Putting $x=s-a,y=s-b,z=s-c$ and defining $f(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{u^2+v^2}-u\right)$, we can write this as $$x=f(y,l)+f(z,l)$$ We obviously get also the corresponding equations $$y=f(z,m)+f(x,m)\text{ and }z=f(x,n)+f(y,n)$$ Now fix $l,m,n$ and regard $x,y,z$ simply as real variables. Let $K=[0,l]\times[0,m]\times[0,n]\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and define $F:K\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by $$F(x,y,z)=(f(y,l)+f(z,l),f(z,m)+f(x,m),f(x,n)+f(y,n))$$ The preceding work shows that $(x,y,z)$ is a fixed point of $F$ iff the triangle with side lengths $a=y+z,b=z+x,c=x+y$ has angle bisector lengths $l,m,n$.

Note that $0\le f(u,v)\le \frac{1}{2}v$, so $F(x,y,z)\in K$ for $(x,y,z)\in K$. So by the Brouwer fixed point theorem, $F$ must have a fixed point.

We have now established that *some* triangle has the given bisector lengths. It remains to show that it is unique. Fortunately only a little more work is required. We show that if $(x,y,z)\ne(x',y',z')$ then the distance between $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$ is strictly less than the distance between $F(x,y,z)$ and $F(x',y',z')$. It follows that they cannot both be fixed points.

Note that $\left(\sqrt{y^2+l^2}-\sqrt{y'^2+l^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{y^2+l^2}+\sqrt{y'^2+l^2}\right)=y^2-y'^2=(y-y')(y+y')$, so we have $2|f(y,l)-f(y',l)|=|\sqrt{y^2+l^2}-y-\sqrt{y'^2+l^2}+y'|=|y-y'|\left|1-\frac{y+y'}{\sqrt{y^2+l^2}+\sqrt{y'^2+l^2}}\right|\le|y-y'|$ with the inequality strict for $y\ne y'$.

So we have $|F(x,y,z)-F(x',y',z')|^2\le |f(y,l)-f(y',l)+f(z,l)-f(z',l)|^2+|f(z,m)-f(z',m)+f(x,m)-f(x',m)|^2+|f(x,n)-f(x',n)+f(y,n)-f(y',n)|^2<\left(\frac{1}{2}|y-y'|+\frac{1}{2}|z-z'|\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}|z-z'|+\frac{1}{2}|x-x'|\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}|x-x'|+\frac{1}{2}|y-y'|\right)^2$.

Note that the inequality is strict because at least one of $|x-x'|,|y-y'|,|z-z'|$ is non-zero.

Adding the non-negative quantity $\left(\frac{1}{2}|y-y'|-\frac{1}{2}|z-z'|\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}|z-z'|-\frac{1}{2}|x-x'|\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}|x-x'|-\frac{1}{2}|y-y'|\right)^2$ the rhs becomes $|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2+|z-z'|^2$ and we have established $|F(x,y,z)-F(x',y',z')|<|(x,y,z)-(x',y',z')|$ as promised.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, but it needs a picture.

As per my comments, I'd love for someone to show how the following "bisecting" segments create a triangle.  Because they clearly *don't*, the proof needs to include when segments do and *do not* create a triangle to be complete.  You need to figure out under what conditions do segments create a triangle and then you need to figure out whether or not bisectors determine a triangle.  It's *not* an easy proof and there is *not* going to be an easy proof of it.

It's one thing to assume a triangle and prove that its bisectors uniquely determine that triangle.  It's quite a different thing to start with segments and say 1) do the segments form bisectors of a triangle and 2) if so, then do they uniquely determine the triangle.

[image]

Comment: You misunderstand the question. It is not about directions or lines, it is about *lengths*: prove that any three (positive) lengths $r,s,t$ uniquely determine a triangle (up to isometry). In other words, they determine the lengths of the triangle's sides $a,b,c$.

Comment: @almagest If so, then I indeed have misunderstood the question.